# Will Symlinking Just in Time Compilers Break my System

Tags: python, lua, jit, pypy

LuaJIT is way faster than Lua and PyPy is much faster than Python.
But most projects still use the `#!/usr/bin/env lua` or `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang, so I know that I can symlink `/usr/bin/luajit` to `/usr/local/bin/lua` to force all Lua programs to use LuaJIT instead. And the same is true for Python. I have three questions:

1. Are there any downsides to doing this?
2. Will this break my system or cause programs not to work?
3. Is there code that will only work for the non-JIT interpreter?

Comment: Regarding to Lua: 2) LuaJIT is Lua 5.1, Lua is (usually) Lua 5.4, they are not 100% compatible. 3) Yes,  for example, `print(3//2)`

Comment: Since LuaJIT is a lot faster, why don't they update it more often than they update Lua?

Comment: Different teams.  Different goals.